# When comparing double arrays, how do I account for the rounding error?

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea, junit, tdd

Example:

```
(Actual) array: 0.0402666113, 0.2355691
(Expected) array: 0.04027, 0.23557
```

I'm trying to write a JUnit test to see whether or not my expected array matches the actual array. In the example given above, the test should pass (i.e. arrays are equal) - however, in practice they don't. I would get a message along the lines of 'arrays differed at index 0, expected: 0.0402666113; actual:0.04027'. I assume this is due to the precision of the numbers. Is there a way to compare these arrays without using a for-loop?

I'm currently trying to compare them using this line:

```
assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

I have seen examples where they would do something like this:

```
final double delta = 0.0001;
assertArrayEquals(expected, actual, delta);
```

This should work, however, I get 'Cannot resolve method assertArrayEquals(double[], double[], double)'. Is there an equivalent method that I can use in my JUnit version (4.12) - if not, how can I update my JUnit in IntelliJ? I have only started to use this IDE recently.

Really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: `assertArrayEquals` will also be using a loop somewhere.

Comment: You can manually do the math using division by the precision followed by rounding eg Math.round(a/0.0001) == Math.round(b/0.0001)

Comment: why not write custom array equals and pass `boolean` to assert on ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - There's no way to write an equality method for this that would also conform to the contract of `equals()` - one would need to write a `nearlyEquals()` method (or something).

Comment: @Oliver yes, *custom* array equals is what I meant

Comment: TestNG has [a method that does exactly that](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/internal/junit/ArrayAsserts.html#assertArrayEquals-double:A-double:A-double-) via a `delta` parameter. Not sure about junit...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the difference between the two doubles, and make sure they are compared up to n digits precision. If you for example want to compare 0.0402666113 and 0.04027, you could write a condition for n=4 like :

```
if (Math.abs(expected[i] - actual[i]) < 1.e-4f) {
    // Validates!
}
else{
    // Failed validation.
}
```

Thus, using our numbers above, the absolute value of their difference is lower than the tolerance, so they are considered "equal".

Comment: Indeed, this is the standard answer out of Numerical Methods textbooks. You've got to specify some tolerance and be ready to accept differences that fall within it.

Comment: His question implies that he understands that floating point numbers should be compared using a delta value. He is asking how to do that in an elegant way with JUnit. Your answer is therefore not at all answering his question.